# Please help - mysql query problems

Tags: mysql

When I use these query, it is not working properly.
What is problem?

[image]

```
WITH T1 AS
(select A, B  from TB1  where ~~  
union 
select A, B from TB1   where ~~ )
select A, B from T1
```

This query works fine.

```
select * from (select A, B  from TB1  where ~~  
union 
select A, B from TB1   where ~~ ) AS T1
```

Comment: What's the version of your mysql? CTEs are supported from v8.0 only.

Comment: when I check , the version is 5.7.X
> show variables like 'version';
http://postgresguide.com/cool/ctes.html